# Send Ethereum transaction, Web3.js without source address, but with source private key?

Tags: node.js, ethereum, web3js

I've just started using Web3.js with node v8.10 and I wanted to check if a specific use-case was at all possible (and being the novice that I am, I probably haven't realised how to do it yet):

Is it at all possible to send a transaction from a source address, to a destination address, with ONLY the source address' private key & the destination address? and not the source address itself? Or is any transaction, RAW or SIGNED, only ever possible, with the source and destination address? (private key being optional in the case of signed transactions)?

Comment: You never need the source address. Perhaps you could share your code and be specific about where you got stuck.

Comment: Thanks a @smarx! As mentioned below, I was able to successfully derive the address from the private key using the ethereumjs-util library.

Comment: That's fine, but there's no need, since you don't need the address.

Comment: Yes; I actually realised that eventually, after reading up on the sendSignedTransaction method; but however, within that method, the nonce ends up getting calculated using: `web3.utils.toHex(web3.eth.getTransactionCount(srcAddr));`

is this not required? could you possibly calculate the nonce without the source address?

Comment: Fair point. To sign a transaction, you don't need the address, but to fetch information about the account (nonce, balance), you do need the address.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can derive the source address from the the private key.
See answers on https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/11253/ethereumjs-how-to-get-public-key-from-private-key

Comment: Thanks a ton for your help @gaiazov! As you suggested, I was able to use the 'ethereumjs-util' library and the 'privateToAddress' method to derive the source address from the private key.

`let srcAddr = ethUtilLib.privateToAddress(privateKey).toString('hex');`